# Synchronize AD user groups with backend service

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito

I am not sure if the question is descriptive enough for what i am trying to accomplish so let me try to elaborate. Because even i am not sure how to properly set the question. So i will tell more about the big picture of what i am trying to do.

I am building an application that uses AWS Cognito for user authentication and authorization. But authorization part is in a way not directly done via Cognito (more about it a bit later)

In Cognito i added as a third part identity provider Azure AD via OIDC. I also have backend service that will hold user's roles in its own database. Now, for users that are going to be added to user pool via AD i need to replicate their groups in AD as a role in my service database. (So if i have a user in AD that is part of the group ADMIN I need to get that group and put it in my own db as a role for that specific user).

Now the idea is to use MS Graph for syncing groups with roles in my service. But the point is that then i would need credentials of the AD user that has the rights to see that info in AD. Which is not really what i am trying to accomplish.

My guess is that this can be done in all at once scenario (which would require the "GODs" user in AD credentials, which is not an option), or one by one (as they login to Cognito via AD as Idp).

So to sum it up, my question is can i integrate the call to MS Graph when user logs in with its ad (microsoft) credentials, that in a way i get the info about his group when he tries to log in to Cognito userpool?

I understand that this probably is very unclear, but i am not quite sure how to put it in a simple way.

If anyone can help me out, i would appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to integrate the call to MS Graph.

Just include Groups claim in your token as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes). You just need to modify the "groupMembershipClaims" field in application manifest:

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"
```

Then the token will contain the Ids of the groups that the use belongs to like below :

```
{
  "groups": ["{group id}"]
}
```